# NPAPI plugin is not reflecting in chrome://plugins

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, npapi

I have written one NPAPI plugin which has MIME type as " VALUE "MIMEType", "application/x-shockwave-flash|application/futuresplash""......

when I say chrome://plugins in the URL address bar , I am not getting my plugin reflected there.
Please suggest me where I am going wrong. 
OS :- winXP
Chrome version is :- 22.0.1229.79 m

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you can't steal someone else's mimetype; if you do, the browser manufacturers will blacklist your plugin. (Well, I don't speak for them, but that's what the developers at Mozilla told me, and I'd expect them to know).

Secondly, you haven't provided nearly enough information for us to guess what might be wrong; are your STRINGS resources in your .rc file set up right? Can you post them as part of the question?

Have you considered using [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org)? That would solve a lot of problems for you and jump-start you on working on the stuff you actually care about.

Alternately, if you'll post some useful information (like code snippets from your .rc file) we can try to help you figure out where you've gone wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response. please use this following link to look at my rc file."https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-D4QxEE1pFDadkLTnwCcpX5rjlkDGMBS4hKI6p_83HM/edit"

Comment: Your plugin *will* be blacklisted if you don't change that mimetype. In fact, I wouldn't be at all surprised if the browser is hardcoded to realize that your plugin cannot possibly be the valid flash plugin and is ignoring it for that reason